# Place UIButton randomly on the view

Tags: ios4

Thank you for a great site, I am a biginner in iOS programming and find this site immensely helpfull.

Actualy I have 2 questions:

1) How to transform NSString to NSAray of chars?
2) How to place UIButons **randomly** on the view when each button.title shows one char from new char array?

I would like to do it **programaticaly**.

Answer (score 0):

1. To transform  NSString to NSAray of chars:

   ```
   NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
   initWithCapacity:[myString length]]; 
   for (int i=0; i < [myString length]; i++) 
   { 
   NSString *ichar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:i ]]; 

   [characters addObject:ichar]; 
   }
   ```

2.place UIButons randomly on the view when each button.title shows one char from new char array

```
    UIButton *charButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRect(<Your required frame>)];
    charButton.titleLabel.text = [characters objectAtIndex:<ur required value>];
    [self.view addsubView:charbutton]
```